CMAKE error while building the application (No SOURCES given to target)
I am trying to build an application that will generate an .elf file. This build is done with the Hi-tech compiler and CMAKE environment. I have some .c source files, corresponding .h files, and generated files from another tool. Below are my CMake files.
Cmakelists.txt
 include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/main_test.cmake)
    include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/test/test2.cmake)

main_test.cmake
set(PROJ_NAME "Test_Project")
set(PROJ_EXECUTABLE_NAME "my_application")

add_executable(${PROJ_EXECUTABLE_NAME})

set_target_properties(${PROJ_EXECUTABLE_NAME}
    PROPERTIES
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${PROJ_OUTPUT_PATH}/bin"
    OUTPUT_NAME "${PROJ_EXECUTABLE_NAME}"
    SUFFIX ".elf" # extension
)

test2 make file
set(MY_SRC_PATH "${PROJ_CMAKE_CONFIG_ROOT}/temp/testfiles.cmake")

if(EXISTS ${MY_SRC})
    set(MYSRC_LIB_NAME MYSRC)
    set(MYSRC_ASM_LIB_NAME MYSRC_ASM)
    set(MYSRC_INTERFACE_LIB_NAME MYSRC_INTERFACE)
    include(${MY_SRC})
    message(STATUS "files are included")
else()
    message(SEND_ERROR "Couldn't find config file: ${MY_SRC}")
endif()

target_link_libraries(${PROJ_EXECUTABLE_NAME} PUBLIC ${MYSRC_LIB_NAME} ${MYSRC_ASM_LIB_NAME} ${MYSRC_INTERFACE_LIB_NAME}) #link files

target_link_options(${PROJ_EXECUTABLE_NAME} PUBLIC -Wl,--whole-archive)

The main CMake file will call another make file and include the .c files.
testfiles.cmake
include_header_all(LOCAL_INC "${MYCODE_SRC_PATH}/component/testscript/src") #.h files include function
include_source_all(LOCAL_SRC "${IMMUTABLE_SRC_PATH}/component/testscript/src") #.c files include function
include_assembly_all(LOCAL_ASM "${GENERATED_SRC_PATH}") #Generated files from another tool include function

add_library(${MYSRC_LIB_NAME} STATIC ${LOCAL_SRC})
add_library(${MYSRC_ASM_LIB_NAME} STATIC ${LOCAL_ASM})
add_library(${MYSRC_INTERFACE_LIB_NAME} INTERFACE)

target_include_directories(${MYSRC_INTERFACE_LIB_NAME} INTERFACE ${LOCAL_INC})

While building, I am getting the 'No SOURCES given to target' error. All the paths are correct and given to cmake file. But I am getting below error.
No SOURCES given to target: my_application

If anybody knows what I am missing here, please help me solve this error so that I can understand what I am doing wrong.

You create the executable with add_executable(${PROJ_EXECUTABLE_NAME}), but doesn't provide source files for it. Source files could be provided in the same add_executable call or with target_sources command.

@Tsyvarev Library file is bound with LOCAL_SRC , LOCAL_ASM and LOCAL_INC which include c files. finally target_link_libraries is linked with executable. Is this correct approach ?

The error message is not about library and the way how your executable is linked to it. The error message is about executable itself: there is no source files associated with it. Do you want to create an executable which only incorporates the code of the libraries it is linked with? Normally, an executable defines main function, which is normally absent in libraries.

@Tsyvarev Yes I want to link libraries to it. I want to make a .elf file along with libraries.

You could create an empty source file, and add it to your executable. This will suppress the error about absent SOURCES.

@Tsyvarev That's for the hint.. I think I was missing target_sources for executable.

As per the @Tsyvarev Comment, I have updated the target_sources for the executable. Like, int main(){ return 0;} . It worked.
